# query search returning same result twice

Tags: javascript, cordova, azure, azure-mobile-services

I recently learned that azure mobile services limits their query search to 50 (or 1000 if you change the default), but my app needs to be able to access unlimited records. I created this service to return a list that contains all of the records. I made the skip count 1 because I wanted to make sure it worked on a small scale before doing a skip count like 50. After debugging this code it keeps returning two of the same records with one of them different. There are three completely different records in my database so I am confused why it is picking up one of them twice. I made sure that when the request was made that skip amount was either 0,1,2.

```
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {



  var x = 0
  var total = 1;

  list = [];
  console.log(list.length);

  while(x <= 3){
      x++;

    var query = table.where(where).includeTotalCount().skip(skipAmount).take(1).read().done(function (results) {

      total = results.totalCount;

      if(results[0] != undefined)
      {

        for (var i = results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          list.push(results[i]);
          console.log(results[i]);
        }



      }
      else
      {

        resolve(list);
      }




    }, function (err) {
      reject(err);

    });

    skipAmount++;
  }

});
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use the `.orderBy()` or `.orderByDescending()` query methods to make sure that the sorted data are returned.

```
table
    .where(where)  
    .orderBy('updatedAt')
    .includeTotalCount()
    .skip(skipAmount)
    .take(1)
    .read() 
    .then(success, failure);
```